# Submitting a solution for SPOJ implemented with Threads

Tags: c, multithreading

I have just implemented a solution for a problem in Sphere Online Judge (SPOJ). The problem consists in finding out if 2 deterministic automatons are equivalent.

This is the thing: I made it using threads (I chose C language) and to make it work, the command you need to put in your shell is something like:

gcc a.c -lpthread -o a

How does SPOJ run this? Does it know this has to be used to make the threads work?...

Comment: SPOJ's command line arguments are fixed and do not depend on the code you've submitted. I.e., it will never run -lpthread. In fact, they **don't** want you running multiple threads, just like they don't want you opening files or sockets.

Comment: Which problem are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot provide it any instructions for linking your program, or even compile time options, including thos for diagnostics.

I'm courious, though: have you tried to submit your solution?  Perhaps SPOJ is smart enough to provide at least a few libraries beyond libc, such as libm and perhaps even libpthreads.

Comment: Yes I sent it, and it wasn't smart enough lol. Anyway, I guess it's because what you've answered to me.